# php, phpMyAdmin sql error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want it when a row gets inserted in a table the date only is inserted automatically.
In phpMyAdmin

```
Name: c_date
Type: date
Length/ Value:
Null: No
```

the rest are blank.

But this sets the date to 0000-00-00.

Can someone please tell me how to?

Thanks

Comment: where is your code and schema?

Comment: ALTER TABLE `cart` ADD `c_time` DATE NOT NULL AFTER `total`;

Answer (score -1):

```
Null: No
```

This is your issue.

If null values aren't permitted, MySQL will convert an empty/null/invalid value into `0000-00-00`. If you permit null values, you should be good to go.

If you want a date to *automatically* be added when rows are created, consider [a `TIMESTAMP` field with a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: FYI: Not my downvote. [I asked for clarification here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024140/php-phpmyadmin-sql-error#comment87064303_50024140) and now seeing they responded with "lmdlmfldmlfmldm". Edit: now they deleted that comment.

Comment: i don't want to use timestamp.since timestamp have time in them,And i want to select distinct dates.

Comment: @Fortie You can't default a `DATE` column like this. There are various approaches - doing it in the application itself, a MySQL trigger, or using a `TIMESTAMP` field with MySQL's `DATE()` sort of functions to just analyze against the date part of its value.